# Logging Etiquette

Tags: c++, c, linux, logging

I have a server program that I am writing. In this program, I log allot. Is it customary in logging (for a server) to overwrite the log of previous runs, append to the file with some sort of new run header, or to create a new log file (it won't be restarted too often).

Which of these solutions is the way of doing things under Linux/Unix/MacOS?

Also, can anyone suggest a logging library for C++/C? I need one, regardless of the answer to the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in /var/log/...you'll see that files are structured like

```
serverlog
serverlog.1
serverlog.2
```

This is done by `logrotate` which is called in a cronjob. But everything is simply in chronological order within the files. So you should just append to the same log file each time, and let logrotate split it up if needed.

You can also add a configuration file to /etc/logrotate.d/ to control how a particular log is rotated. Depending on how big your logfiles are, it might be a good idea to add here information about your logging. You can take a look at other files in this directory to see the syntax.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: See `man logrotate`, or google. The short version is that it does exactly what Magnesium says: splits/rotates the logs. The configuration that supports the logs for the things on your system is in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*`

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh logrotate is a daemon that runs on Linux (maybe other Unix, I'm not sure) and keeps log files under control. Every now and then it starts a new logfile `logfile`, archiving the previous one as `logfile.1` and moving that archive to `logfile.2`, etc. It also keeps only a few archives, so that the space used doesn't grow out of control.

Comment: Ok. Thank makes sense, and sounds like the usual nice simple approach of Linux. I'll use it.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh : It's a great little daemon. Also, as for the C/C++ logging library, logging is such a simple thing that I would just make your own function: `writeLog(char* msg)` which writes a new line to the logfile, containing `timestamp \t msg`. You could even make it a class if you wanted, but even that is overkill IMHO.

Comment: @Magnesium: I think I'll take your suggestion. It's mush easier to write your own then spending time trying to build code found in the depths of the internet.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather complex issue. I don't think that there is a silver bullet that will kill all your concerns in one go.

The first step in deciding what policy to follow would be to set your requirements. *Why* is each entry logged? What is its purpose? In most cases this will result in some rather concrete facts, such as:

- You need to be able to *compare* the current log with past logs. Even when an error message is self-evident, the *process* that led to it can be determined much faster by playing spot-the-difference, rather than puzzling through the server execution flow diagram - or, worse, its source code. This means that you need *at least* one log from a past run - overwriting blindly is a definite *No*.
- You need to be able to *find* and *parse* the logs without going out of your way. That means using whatever facilities and policies are already established. On Linux it would mean using the [`syslog`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) facility for important messages, to allow them to appear in the usual places.

There is also some good advice to heed:

- Time is important. No only because there's never enough of it, but also because log files without proper timestamps for each entry are practically useless. Make sure that each entry has a timestamp - most system-wide logging facilities will do that for you. Make also sure that the clocks on all your computers are as accurate as possible - using NTP is a good way to do that.
- Log entries should be as self-contained as possible, with minimal cruft. You don't need to have a special header with colors, bells and whistles to announce that your server is starting - a simple *MyServer (PID=XXX) starting at port YYYYY* would be enough for `grep` (or the search function of any decent log viewer) to find.
- You need to determine the granularity of each logging channel. Sending several GB of debugging log data to the system logging daemon is *not* a good idea. A good approach might be to use separate log files for each logging level and facility, so that e.g. user activity is not mixed up with low-level data that in only useful when debugging the code.
- Make sure your log files are in *one* place, preferably separated from other applications. A directory with the name of your application is a good start.
- Stay within the norm. Sure you may have devised a new nifty logfile naming scheme, but if it breaks the conventions in your system it could easily confuse even the most experienced operators. Most people will have to look through your more detailed logs in a critical situation - don't make it harder for them.
- Use the system log handling facilities. E.g. on Linux that would mean appending to the same file and letting an external daemon like `logrotate` to handle the log files. Not only would it be less work for you, it would also automatically maintain any general logging policies as a whole.
- Finally: Always copy log important data to the system log as well. Operators watch the system logs. Please, please, *please* don't make them have to look at other places, just to find out that your application is about to launch the ICBMs...

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c

For the logging, I would suggest creating a new log file and clean it using a certain frequency to avoid it growing too fat. Overwrite logs of previous login is usually a bad idea.